# src-set works properly in devtools scaling up from mobile, but not down from desktop?

Tags: image, responsive-design, srcset

I have an image with the following code (beautified for reading)

```
<figure>
  <img width="1920" height="1280" src="image-1920x1280.jpeg" decoding="async" loading="lazy"
  srcset="image-1920x1280.jpeg 1920w,
  image-150x100.jpeg 150w,
  image-360x240.jpeg 360w, 
  image-1200x800.jpeg 1200w,
  image-480x320.jpeg 480w,
  image-640x427.jpeg 640w,
  image-720x480.jpeg 720w,
  image-960x640.jpeg 960w,
  image-1440x960.jpeg 1440w"
  sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px">
</figure>
```

Using Chrome DevTools Network tab with cache disabled and using Ctrl+Shift+R to do hard refreshes, I'm trying to evaluate whether src-set works properly. I have also done the same in an incognito tab to be sure I'm not seeing things.

I noticed that when I load the page at a small breakpoint, and then scale the width up, src-set loads images as the screen gets larger. But when I load the page at full-width, then scale down, src-set does not load any images as the screen gets smaller. **TLDR: src-set appears to work from mobile-upward, but not desktop-downward. Is this behavior intentional or is something wrong with my code?**

I tried scouring the internet for others who may have noticed this behavior, but found nothing.